# Как реализовать самоуничтожение записи по наступлении даты?

Tags: laravel

В таблице указана дата когда запись должна быть удалена, как сделать функцию которая будет срабатывать автоматически, без вызова?

Comment: эээ триггер ?
таблица и субд как называется?

Comment: @sterx Триггер выполняется только по изменяющему событию (CREATE/UPDATE/DELETE) на именно этой записи таблицы, чего можно ждать до морковкина заговенья. И не срабатывает на событие SELECT - т.е. запись будет продолжать попадать в выборки. Кроме того, обычно триггер не может удалять записи из таблицы, на событие которой срабатывает - тем более ту запись, на изменение коей он сработал.

Comment: Какая DBMS? В большинстве их имеется свой планировщик, способный выполнить требуемую операцию.

Comment: Вы хотите удалить запись когда наступит дата удаления? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Пользуйтесь [Laravel events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#events).**

Я вам приведу пример с методом `boot()` в моделе который также является триггером.

Допустим есть `action` который удаляет пользователя по `id`.Но вы бы хотели  произвести какое либо другое(другие) действие автоматически.

**Например удалить все его документы:**

**User Controller:**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $user = User::findorFail($id);
    $user->delete();
    return redirect('user/index')->withSuccess('Successfully deleted!');
}
```

**User Model:**

```
public function documents()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Document');
}

protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($user) {
        foreach ($user->documents() as $document) {
            Storage::delete($document->filename);
            $document->delete();
        }
    });
}
```